# Splitting content between divs based on length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following layout styled to appear as a sheet of printed paper on a writing desk:

```
<div class="paper">
    <div class="header">
        [stuff]
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        [long stuff]
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        [stuff]
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to split the contents of the div "content" between several divs as so as to make it appear that the contents are literally paginated across several sheets of paper with each sheet of paper being ~1000px tall.

```
<div class="paper">
    <div class="header">
        [stuff]
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        [part 1 of long stuff]
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paper">
    <div class="content">
        [part 2 of long stuff]
    </div>
</div>
<div class="paper">
    <div class="content">
        [part 3 of long stuff]
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        [stuff]
    </div>
</div>
```

How feasible is it to do this?

Comment: @drakenin , why do you want to split the html like that?

Comment: Explain the scenario... how do you know where to break the data in the content?

Comment: might not need to split content at all by using CSS3 column properties ( assuming can handle only performing in browsers that support CSS3)

Comment: @charlietfl I'd be perfectly happy having only CSS3 capable browsers seeing the split, although I am unsure as to how I would force it to show the content vertically.

Comment: @kobe The page is styled to look like a sheet of paper on a writing desk and it was requested that the content paginate so that it appeared that it were printed onto a series of sheets of paper. Ideally, the content should break every ~1000px or so.

Comment: @ATOzTOA The page is styled to look like a sheet of paper on a writing desk and it was requested that the content paginate so that it appeared that it were printed onto a series of sheets of paper. Ideally, the content should break every ~1000px or so.

Comment: What do you mean by 1000px? Where are you getting the actual text from? Can you share an example?

Comment: @ATOzTOA The text is pulled from a markdown file, converted to HTML with the python markdown2 module and the page its self is then generated a hackish python script. The text its self is usually in the form of an actual letter, long form prose with the occasional image.

Also, when I say it should break every ~1000px or so, to continue with the page metaphor each page would be about 1000px tall and have a min-height of 1000px. Ideally, when the content gets too large, a second page should be created and the excess content placed there. Am I being clear enough?

Comment: If that is the case, the viable option maybe be keep track of the height of the div while data in HTML is being appended. Use an id for each page like content_1, content_2. And use jquery like $("#content_1").append("some text"); and check $("#content_1").height();

Comment: 'as so as to' -> 'so as to', and you've incorrectly used the word 'literally'. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the case, the viable option maybe be keep track of the height of the div while data in HTML is being appended.

```
<div class="content" id="content_1">
```

Use an id for each page like content_1, content_2. And use jquery like :

```
$("#content_1").append("some text"); 
if($("#content_1").height() >= 1000) {
    $("#content_1").parent().append('<div class="content" id="content_2"></div>');
}
```

Do this in a loop like

```
index = 0;
$("#content_" + index)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you could use the CSS3 column properties. Here's a quick and dirty [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevanhetzel/ev4KV/) to get you started, code below:

**CSS**

```
.content {
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    -moz-column-width: 100px; 
    -webkit-column-width: 100px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px; 
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px; 
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 25px;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <strong>HEADER STUFF</strong>
</div>

<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id libero est. Integer porttitor consectetur adipiscing. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec id ipsum non tortor dapibus imperdiet quis in lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque malesuada arcu at magna suscipit condimentum. Integer congue pretium nunc at pretium. Vestibulum vel turpis in turpis gravida pretium. 
</div>

<div class="footer">
<strong>FOOTER STUFF</strong>
</div>​
```

You would then have to have your background image of paper (assuming that's what you're using) either repeat 3 times across (or however many pieces of paper you want) or just have 3 pieces of paper in one image file, spaced how you want it to.