# Splitting data into pages depending on height (creating a printable song book)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im currently trying to make a song book for eg. birthdays, weddings etc. where you choose a couple of songs and then the songs will be shown on the website in the size of A5 paper, and the users can edit some text there, before converting it to a PDF. Currently i create a new page for each song, but i would like to fill out as much space as possible. By having more than one song per page, or atleast have some verses of another song on the same page, and show the rest on next page.

```
A5 size
Height: 793.7px
Width:  559.3px
```

```
<div class="songpage currentpage">
     <h4>Song #1</h4>
     <div class="verse">
              <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>1 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>2 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>3 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>4 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>5 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>6 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>7 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>8 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>9 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
     </div>

     <h4>Song #2</h4>
     <div class="verse">
              <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>1 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>2 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>3 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>4 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>5 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>6 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>7 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>8 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                            <p>9 - Lipsum Lipsum</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
The green line indicates where the song should be split up and continue on next page.


Lets say that
<h4> = 60px height
<p>  = 90px height
```

How can i check elements height and split them into new pages (closing tags and creating a new div.songpage) when the max height is reached. max height is 793.7px.

If anyone can come with an example of some sort or guide me in the right direction -  i'll appreciate it!

Comment: maybe this stackoverflow question can help?
Looks similar to me.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907718/splitting-content-between-divs-based-on-length][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907718/splitting-content-between-divs-based-on-length

Comment: I thought of that already. the problem is my elements are more nested and the verses are split up as shown in the picture, so its a bit more tricky to figure out. But thanks for the link.

Comment: My own first thoughts were, you probably could do some calculations with javascript, or even beter, use a controller and service, where you could do the math before the page is loaded, and use a list of lyricPage-model objects? But I don't know what technologies you use or how you build your site.

Comment: Im trying to figure out the right way to do this with JavaScript by calculating the different elements, but right now im stuck. because i cant figure out how to proceed correctly with the calculations of elements and splitting up the data when maximum height is reached. I am building this in Laravel